# cannot resolve method setcontentview(android.widget.TextView)

Tags: android, android-fragments

How to setContentView in a fragment?
I having error with setContentView(tvv);
Any helps will be appreciated.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGpxy.png)

Continue

```
 Button btnBF = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnBF);
        btnBF.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(),SelectImage.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
            }
        });
        return view;
    }



}
```

Comment: You can't call setContentView() in a fragment.

Comment: You don't call setContentView from within a Fragment, rather you override the onCreateView method in the Fragment and return the View to be displayed.

Answer (score 1):

What are you doing there? lol..
You don't need to set the textView.. it's already there.
You need to return the "view" elemnt.